# "No item could be found" error when installing app

Tags: 2.1-eclair, google-play-store, app-brain, htc-wildfire

I receive 'no item could be found error' when I try to install some apps such as:

- Busybox
- Gems miner
- Springpad

All apps are listed in AppBrainer or on their webpages but not on Market.

What is causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that AppBrain lists all apps irrespective of the phone you are using to browse it, whereas the market seems to filter apps to show only ones that are supported by your phone or version of Android (not sure which, but seems most likely version of Android).  Since Wildfire is still on 2.1 I guess the apps you are trying to install are 2.2+.  As far as I am concerned this makes AppBrain pretty useless for the Wildfire.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this before when I try to cancel an install from within AppBrain. If you have the FastWeb Installer loaded then it sees that as an indication of wanting to uninstall, even if the application is not really loaded on the phone.